# Bash script to calculate remaining days to expire SSL certs in a website

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssl

I have a website called `xplosa.com` and it has a valid SSL certificates and I went through bash script should be able to calculate remaining day counts to expire. I know there are plenty of alternative ways to do this job but I love to work with Ubuntu bash . BTW I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04`

This is my **sample logic**

```
#!/bin/bash

get_the_cert_expiry_date() {
    # command to retrieve the expiry date
}

currentDate="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
website="xplosa.com"
certExpDate="$(get_the_cert_expiry_date)"
count=$((currentDate - certExpDate))

echo "remaining days for expiry: ${count}"
```

- Is this a right logic?
- How to implement `get_the_cert_expiry_date`

Comment: Shouldn't be `count="certExpDate-currentDate"` ?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli yes can count like that but the thing is we should get the cert expiry date . the script for get date value from a website . How  to do that ?

Comment: @karlsebal Please do not abuse the system

Comment: @karlsebal This is the public community please don't spoil if you don't even know the answer

Comment: That's not work anymore I need a script to calculate remaining day counts for my SSL certificate expiry let's say today Dec 26th and my SSL certificate would expire in Dec 28th, then the output should be 2 days left . That's all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
#!/bin/bash

website="xplosa.com"
certificate_file=$(mktemp)
echo -n | openssl s_client -servername "$website" -connect "$website":443 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > $certificate_file
date=$(openssl x509 -in $certificate_file -enddate -noout | sed "s/.*=\(.*\)/\1/")
date_s=$(date -d "${date}" +%s)
now_s=$(date -d now +%s)
date_diff=$(( (date_s - now_s) / 86400 ))
echo "$website will expire in $date_diff days"
rm "$certificate_file"
```

Comment: Output of this code tells ``` unable to load certificate
140490086364224:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
 will expire in 0 days  ```

Comment: updated answer... check now @soldier

Comment: I suggest to add `rm "$certificate_file"` to clean up again.

Comment: You could get rid of a few lines and the need to save and delete a file by having this:
`date=$(echo -n | openssl s_client -servername $website -connect $website:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate | sed "s/.*=\(.*\)/\1/")`

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198619/bash-script-to-calculate-remaining-days-to-expire-ssl-certs-in-a-website

### Read Site Certificate and save as File ###
echo -n | openssl s_client -servername $1 -connect $1:443 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > $1.crt


### Get Full Expiratoin Date ###
date=$(openssl x509 -in $1.crt -enddate -noout | sed "s/.*=\(.*\)/\1/" | awk -F " " '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}')

### Convert Expiration Date in Epoch Format ###
date_s=$(date -j -f "%b %d %T %Y" "$date" "+%s")

### Get Curent Date in Epoch Format ###
now_s=$(date +%s)

### Calculate Time Difference ###
date_diff=$(( (date_s - now_s) / 86400 ))

echo "Certificate for $1 will expire in $date_diff days"
```

Comment: answer seems like the same as above. it would be better to edit the accepted answer instead of adding a duplicate. @Ronen

Comment: There is no `-j` option in `date` command.

Comment: date -j seems to exist in BSD/MacOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43927574/5155484

Comment: The working version for other systems is: `date_s=$(date -d "%b %d %T %Y" -d "$date" "+%s")`